# How to delete a node from the Hashmap C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, hashmap, nodes

I have an HashMap (struct table). It contains nodes doubly linked with two parameters: key, value.
Hashmap may contains every data type. Insertion of nodes is generic, so the user must choose what data type insert in the hashmap.
My aim is to create a generic function in order to delete a node with a key that I passed him.
When I try to delete a node `canckey` doesn't work. It doesn't compile when I use double arrow. For example :  `temp->prev->next = temp->next;` (in this line of code I'm telling him to update the `next` of the previous node to the one I have to delete.)

**canc.c**

```
struct node{
    void* key;
    void* val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
struct table{
    int size;
    struct node **list;
};

void cancKey(struct table *t, void *key, int(*hash)(void*), int(*comp)(void*, void*)) {
    int pos = (*hash)(key);
    struct node *list = t->list[pos];
    struct node *temp = list;
    if (t->list[pos] == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", "The key doesn't exist.");
        return;
    }
    while (temp) {
        if (((*comp)(temp->key, key)) == 1) {
            if(temp->prev==NULL){
                list->next=temp->next;
                temp->next->prev=NULL;
                temp->next=NULL;
            }else {
                temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->prev = NULL;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
int hashCode(int key){
    return (key%500);
}

int compare(int key,int key2){
    if(key==key2){
        return 1;
    }else return 0;
}

int main(){

    struct table *t; // table creation and data insertion
    int i=1;
    int *p = &i;
    int i1=2;
    int *p2 = &i1;

    cancKey(t,p,hashCode, compare);
    cancKey(t,p2,hashCode, compare);
}
```

Comment: I think you got the `if(temp->prev!=NULL)` backwards, that should be `== NULL`, the branch where it is NULL should not try to access what is in `temp->prev`. Why doubly linked anyway? That's only going to make it more complicated over singly linked and it's not as if there is a benefit to them for this.

Comment: Putting `== NULL`, it doesn't work anyway. @dratenik

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not much of a problem description. Does it do something unexpected (what happens? what did you expect to happen?), does it crash? If you want to make it really easy for people to answer, provide a [mre] where people could see the doesn't-work-ness for themselves.

Comment: it doesn't give an error but when I run the program . When it arrives to the `if` after the `while` it stops. I tried with a lot of `printf` and it doesn't show anything after that point. @dratenik